# Ajax url: parameter and checking for success

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

im not so sure how this works, but where does my success(data) value come from?
must I return a value in url: php/login.php?

```
 $.ajax({     
  url: 'php/login.php',    //must i return a value in login.php?                    
  data: {username:username,password:password},
  type: "POST",    
  dataType: 'json',                  
  success: function(data)          
  {
     if(data == true){
        console.log("sdfsdfs   " + data);
        login.submit();
    }
     else{
        console.log("NO DATA PRESENT");
     }       
  } 
     //else do an alert("please lgo in again");    
 });
```

in php/login.php i query the DB to see if such a user exists and if password match

part of my login.php

```
 <?php
 echo $username = $_POST['username']; //not echo-ing
 echo $password = $_POST['password'];  
 if ($_POST['login']) //check if the submit button is pressed
 {
   $remember = $_POST['remember'];  
   if ($username&&$password) //check if the field username and password have values
   {
     $dbhost = 'localhost';
     $dbuser = 'root';
     $dbpass = '';

     $connect=mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass) or die("Unable to Connect");  
    mysqli_select_db($connect,"clients") or die("Could not open the db");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM clients.users WHERE username='$username'";
    $login = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($login))
    {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($login)) 
        {
            $db_password = $row['password']; 
            if ($password==$db_password)
            {   
                $loginok = TRUE;
                echo json_encode( true );
            } else {
              echo json_encode( false );
              echo "Please re-enter username and password, they did not match";            
              header("Location: ../login.php");
            }      
   ?>
```

Comment: You have to return or echo a value in login.php

Comment: Sure, you must return (output) data in JSON format

Comment: please see amended OP

Answer (score 0):

When you want to return some data using ajax, you need to echo data in your script that will be called by ajax. If the request is successful, it will return everything you echoed in your script into your parameter you specified in success function.

```
success: function(data)          
  {
     // code...
  }
```

so "data" will contain result from your script, then you can do whatever you want.

**EDIT:**

Well, i would solve it like this

```
 $db_password = $row['password']; 

        if ($password==$db_password)
        {   
            echo json_encode(array("status" => "ok", "message" => "Login successful!"));
        } else {
          echo json_encode(array("status" => "error", "message" => "Please re-enter username and password, they did not match!"));         
          //header("Location: ../login.php"); you don't need this
        }
```

you can't echo json, then some text after it. You can, but it is not recommended at all.

Comment: yes thanks but do i return this value in login.php? please see amended OP

Comment: thank you , what will my ajax look like then in success:
i cant remember it anymore :)

Comment: so what's the problem? You want to check with javascript if the user login was successful? You need to specify your problem more precisely :P

Comment: it doesn look like my url: php/login.php is executed, i have some echo's right at the start and it doesnt display

Comment: If your ajax request returns empty result it can mean  that your requested script has some error OR you didn't echo anything OR you echoed NULL value, or zero value.